# create-react-app imported function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, import

I have 2 filter functions exported from helpers.js file:

```
    export const filterSource = (data, source_tags_array) => {
    let accumulator = []
     source_tags_array.forEach( tag => {
         accumulator = data.filter( event => {return event.source_type.includes(tag)})
         // accumulator.concat(...tmp)
     })
    accumulator.sort(function(a,b) {
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)
    })
    return accumulator

}


export const filterTags = (data, tags_array) => {
    let accumulator = []
    tags_array.forEach( tag => {
        data.forEach((event) => {
            if (!accumulator.some(el => el.id === event.id) && event.tags.includes(tag)) {
                accumulator.push(event)
            }
        })
      return accumulator
    })
}
```

And I import them in reducer file:

```
import * as helpers from "../helpers";

export const filter = events_data => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const { access_tags, access_source_tags} = getState().user
        const filteredSource = helpers.filterSource(events_data, access_source_tags)
        const events =  helpers.filterTags(filteredSource, access_tags)
        dispatch(fetchEventsSuccess(events))
    }}
```

While first one (filterSource) works fine the second (filterTags) is **undeifned**

**Screenshot with variables values from debuger**

[image: Screenshot with variables values from debuger]

In case you cannot see image...
filteredSource: Array(160)
events_data: Array(395)
accesss_source_tags: Array(1)
access_tags: Array(1)
**events: UNDEFINED**

The **accumulator** from filterTags in helpers.js on return point is **Array(65)** but for some reason after import is **undefined**...

I tried named imports as well... same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` inside `filterTags` is inside the `forEach`, move it outside and it should work

```
export const filterTags = (data, tags_array) => {
    let accumulator = []
    tags_array.forEach( tag => {
        data.forEach((event) => {
            if (!accumulator.some(el => el.id === event.id) && event.tags.includes(tag)) {
                accumulator.push(event)
            }
        })
    })
    return accumulator
}
```